# Is it posible to implement mTLS on the client side without a truststore?

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, resttemplate

i've been implementing a restTemplate which sends a POST to a server protected with mTLS.  i've implemented the following bean in Springboot. Briefly, I provide the restTemplate with a Keystore and a Truststore (.jks format) to implement the two way ssl connection but i'd need not to use a TrustStore but checking some field of the server certificate in order to validate it.

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public RestTemplate mtlsRestTemplate(KeyStore keystore) throws IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
    if (!isMtlsActivated) {
        return classicRestTemplate();
    }
    SSLContext context;
    try {
        context = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .setProtocol("TLS")
                .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File(trustStoreLocation), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
                .build();
    } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // [...]
    }

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
            .setMaxConnTotal(maxConnectionsTotal)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute)
            .build());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
}
```

My needs come from the server policy when it comes to renewing their certificates. This task will be performed quite often which would force me to check and upload the new certificates constantly and manually (as this operation cannot be automated). I've been reading that, in the server side using Spring Security you could send your own certificate and then check the cn of the client certificate (for example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-rest-apis-with-client-certificates) among other places). Would be there any way of checking the cn (or dn, or any other field, not sure of the most safe one) when using the `.exchange()` method of the RestTemplate generated by my bean?

**Edit1:** I've been trying and i've been able to create a class implementing `CertificateTrustStrategy` and loading it as a TrustMaterial the same way I initialize with the trustStore, but i cannot figure out how to check the validity of the certificate besides the DN. I forgot to explain that i cannot check with a CA certificate the client one but, I could do it with fields that wouldn't change if the CA would change it's certificate.